# vector of structs inline initialization. braced-init-list

Tags: c++, stl

I ran into a strange issue which unfortunately, I cannot reproduce outside my application itself. The situation is as below. I have the following struct.

```
struct Foo {
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
    bool flag;
    float value;
};
```

One of my classes has a member `std::vector<Foo> fooList` which undergoes the following set of operations periodically.

```
void someOperation() {
    UpdateFooList(); //< Updates existing members of fooList
    UseFooList(); //< Do some useful stuff with the new values.
    fooList.clear();

    // Repopulate fooList which is where the problem is. The call below
    // has never worked here. It results in either junk values 
    // in fooList[0] or some of the member values at [0] before the clear() call
    // appear to be retained after the emplace_back
    fooList.emplace_back(Foo{"First", "Second", true, 0.0f}); 
}
```

Here are the things I have tried.

- To make sure there was no data corruption, tried putting in mutexes everywhere there is an access to `fooList`.
- Tried creating a 4 value ctor to Foo with the signature `Foo(const std::string&, const std::string&, bool, float)` and used this ctor instead of the brace-init-list. No luck here.
- Tried replacing `emplace_back` with `push_back` in the code above. This did not help either.
- Tried reproducing these problems in an isolated cpp file and it works exactly as expected.

The only thing that appears to work in the application is if I replace the `emplace_back` with the following two lines.

```
auto fooEntry = Foo{"First", "Second", true, 0.0f};
fooList.push_back(fooEntry); //< This works as expected.
fooList.emplace_back(fooEntry); //< This also works as expected
```

Any thoughts on why the inline calls of `fooList.emplace_back(Foo{"First", "Second", true, 0.0f});` does not work?

I am on `gcc-7.2.0` and the application is compiled using `c++14` standards.

While this bit of information may not be relevant adding it here for completeness. The class under consideration is compiled using `c++14` and exposed via a .so file, while the application itself is compiled using `c++17` and loads the .so. The members of the class under consideration are not exposed outside the class. Just the class methods are public.

Comment: OT but your use of `emplace_back` buys you nothing over `push_back`. You probably want `fooList.emplace_back("First", "Second", true, 0.0f); `

Comment: Sounds like there is some undefined behavior somewhere in your code.  Without a [mcve] there isn't much we can help you with.

Comment: Also, is the `.so` compiled with the same compiler and version as the project?  That could be an issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, this post is a last resort. I have discussed this issue at length with some of my colleagues at work and we could not think of any logical reason why this does not work the way we expect it to.

Comment: Yes, the .so is compiled with different compiler options and standards (c++14 for the .so and c++17 for the application). Could this matter even if none of the class members are exposed?

Comment: just wanted to confirm that this was the source of the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162484/structs-with-the-same-name-namespace-but-different-members 
Once I pushed the definition of Foo inside class itself, the problem went away.