# Structs with the same name/namespace but different members

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I am seeing some strange behavior which I have described in this post [vector of structs inline initialization. braced-init-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161886/vector-of-structs-inline-initialization-braced-init-list?noredirect=1#comment93214350_53161886)

I am hoping to eliminate one possible source of the undefined behavior. I have the following two classes `A` and `B` which both forward declare `struct Foo` but the cpp file defines the actual struct as below.

```
// This is A.h
namespace app {
    struct Foo;
    class A {
    private:
        std::vector<Foo> fooList;
    };
}

// This is A.cpp
struct app::Foo {
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
    unsigned flag;
};


// This is B.h
namespace app {
    struct Foo;
    class B {
    private:
        std::vector<Foo> fooList;
    };
}

// This is B.cpp
struct app::Foo {
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
    bool flag;
    float value;
};
```

Notice, that the struct `Foo` has different members in cpp files `A.cpp`, `B.cpp`. The classes `A` and `B` never expose the member `fooList`. Is it ever possible that since the forward declaration is exactly the same, in files `A.h` and `B.h` for the struct `Foo`, the generated code could be using one or the other. This could explain the issue I was seeing in the linked problem.

In other words, while using the braced-init-list for the struct `Foo` invoked in `B.cpp` is it guaranteed that `Foo` defined in `B.cpp` would be used or it is equally likely that `Foo` defined in `A.cpp` could also be used?

Even as I am writing this, I immediately realize that this implementation is a bad practice as `Foo` itself is internal to the classes `A` and `B` and should really have been declared in the private section of the class itself.

Comment: Note that the C++ standard doesn't allow `vector` of incomplete types. So your code isn't standards compliant.

Comment: @juanchopanza As long as the constructor and destructor have access to the definition, this is fine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This violates the ODR (one definition rule).

The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Absolutely any behavior is permitted by the C++ standard if you do this.  It could "work", it could pick one and discard the other, it could work until you relink, it could format your hard drive.

I have done this in a real live project; we had a matrix header where you could define tokens before including it if it would support float or double.

This "worked" while we never used both versions in the same DLL.  Then we used both versions.

The compiler would pick one size or the other for the structure based on one set of coincidences, and would pick one constructor or other based off a slightly different set of coincidences.  We got memory corruption galore.  But only sometimes on some builds.

We quickly "fixed" it by wrapping the code in a namespace whose name included the scalar type, then `using` brought them into the exterior namespace.

Comment: Interesting. I, for some reason, believed that if the compiler found duplicate definitions in an assembly, it would point it out to me and won't accept it as is.

Comment: @cplusplusrat UB also means that compiler can decide to issue a diagnostic (eg. a warning). But the problem is that compiler works one file at a time. It won't see the double definition in two different files (unless they would be included one into another). And linker doesn't have to deal with classes at all, so it's hard to actually detect such error.